# Spliting a number into equal parts and Add it together to get the same number

Tags: c#, split, numbers, decimal

I need to implement a logic in c# where as I need to split and Add it to together to get the same value.

For example:

> 1.0/6.0442137639369475 = 0.16544749061764519

and when I add

> 0.16544749061764519 + 0.16544749061764519

to make it 1.0 is not working at all it comes as

> 0.99268494370587

not 1.0 exactly.

I am not sure what I am missing...?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "split a number into equal parts"?

Comment: Please show at least 6 sample inputs and outputs to make it clear what you expect.

Comment: `1.0 is not working at all it comes as 0.99268494370587 not 1.0 exactly.` What is this referring to? It sounds like perhaps you have some code already? If so, please include your code in the post.

Comment: 0.16544749061764519 + 0.16544749061764519 is 0.33089498123529038 why you should get 1?

Comment: 0.16544749061764519 + 0.16544749061764519 doesn't equal  0.99268494370587 or 1.0

Comment: I think, by split OP means division

Comment: @Ernis seems so, but "split to eual parts" would then mean divide by 2 ?!?

Comment: The problem is that real numbers (non-integers) are stored in computers in an incomplete way - only a limited number of digits of precision. That makes accuracy suffer.

Comment: It will equal 1.0 when you add 0.16544749061764519 to itself ... 6.0442137639369475[...] times.

Comment: that's because you dividing from 6.044.. not from 6.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use more precise dataformats. Try to use double. If this is not precise enough, what I doubt, you can still search for a more precise implementation.

Comment: I'm not sure precision is the issue when the op is troubled by the fact that 0.16544749061764519 + 0.16544749061764519 doesn't = 1.0.

Comment: By the tags he is using I think he is using decimal format and trying to divide a number by x. Then he is trying to add the outcome x times and that result should he the value he was dividing by x.

Comment: So, rather than just 0.16544749061764519 + 0.16544749061764519 you think he is adding 0.16544749061764519 to itself 6.0442137639369475 times? :-)

Comment: @spodger no, he is adding it 6 times... :-( that gives exactly his 0.99...
I dont know which sense the intended math should make

Comment: @casiosmu yes, it certainly does. I'm still not quite clear what the problem is, though. :-)

Answer (score 0):

if I guess your question correct, you want to do the following math:

`c=a/b`

`d=c+c+c+...` n-times until `a==d`.

this will only work if you use integer numbers for `a` and `b`, with your real number 6.0442137639369475 as `b` it cannot (math law afaik).

And by the way:

your division result `0.16544749061764519` is rounded! The correct result is `0.16544749061764518326`.
So you maybe need another data type as already pointed out.

Comment: Even when I add those values 0.16544749061764518326, the result is 0.99268494370587113, Not excactly 1.0

Comment: of course not, it will never be because if you add it up it is mathematically the same as multipling with *integer* numbers, and the original divider was no integer